# Finding argument of complex number without calculator

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I am solving some exercises in the book I am reading. In this particular exercise I should find real and imaginary part of

$$ \left ( {1 + i \sqrt{3}\over 2}\right )^n$$

My idea was to calculate the argument and the absolute value and then use polar representation.

But I think the idea is not to use a calculator. So I am stuck on 
$$ \arctan \sqrt{3}$$

If I use a calculator to find this value I can easily solve the exercise.

> How to calculate $ \arctan \sqrt{3}$ without using a calculator? Is it
>   possible?

**Edit**

If it's possible any general method is most appreciated since I am already stuck at the next exercise where I am trying to find the argument of $-3+i$.

Comment: Remember, $\arctan\sqrt{3} = \theta \implies \tan \theta = \sqrt{3}$.. Then draw your exact triangles to find the value of $\theta$.

Comment: $$z = 1 \angle{60}$$
$$z^n = 1 \angle{n 60}$$

$$tan(30)=\frac{\sqrt3}3$$
$$tan(60)={\sqrt3}$$

Comment: @Mattos What do you mean by draw the exact triangles? I am now trying to find the argument of $-3 +i$ and I drew a triangle with sides $1$ and $3$.

Comment: there are at least three special angles $\pi/6, \pi/4,$ and $\pi/3$ whose $\sin $ and $\cos$ one is supposed to know. $\cos \pi/6 = \sin \pi/3 = \frac{\sqrt 3}2, \sin \pi/4 = \cos \pi/4 = \sqrt 2/2$ and $\cos \pi/3 = \sin \pi/ 6 = 1/2$

Comment: @Anna See abels answer above for the exact triangles. Also, to calculate the argument, just take $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{1}{-3}$, where $a, b$ are just the coefficients in your equation $z = a + ib$..

Comment: what are you trying to do with $-3 + i?$ you might be able to use trig addition formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an even easier way. You can verify by direct computation that

$$z^6=\left({1+i\sqrt 3\over 2}\right)^6=1$$

and that no smaller power works. This along with the fact that both real and imaginary parts are positive, i.e. in the first quadrant tells you that $z=e^{i\pi\over 3}$, since this is the only $6^{th}$ root of $1$ in the first quadrant. (all others aside from $1$ have an argument at least $120^\circ={2\pi\over 3}$ which is outside the first quadrant.

Then you know that if $n=6k+r$ with $0\le r\le 5$ that the argument is $r$ times that of $z$, i.e. $\theta={\pi r\over 3}$.

Comment: Thanks, is this applicable to any case? I'm already stuck at computing the argument of $-3 +i$.

Comment: Remember, $z = a + ib$, so the principle argument is given by $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a}$ (draw the graph if it confuses you).

Comment: @Mattos Like I said: I already drew a triangle. I don't see what to do with it.

Comment: @Anna that one doesn't work as simply since the normalized real and imaginary parts have square roots of $10$ in the denominator, which are not as easy to work with as the more familiar trig functions. That one you can just list as $\arctan-{1\over 3}$, that cannot be easily computed without a calculator. The point is no method can be applicable to *any* case, because only some of them have $n^{th}$ powers which are real numbers. And if it worked for every case we could always determine the arctan function everywhere, which is known to be impossible.

Comment: Adam: Then is it likely that the author of the book assumes the reader will use a calculator?

Comment: @Anna yes, for many cases that is the case. Although, if I wrote the book I would expect you to write $\arctan -{1\over 3}$ not a numerical answer, because that shows me you understand what is going on, numerical answers aren't frequently useful, because most times the exact decimal isn't the point of the exercises. It is common mathematical practice to leave such things as $\arctan(\text{ stuff})$. If you're really worried, I'd just ask your teacher what he/she prefers.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2})^n$$
$$(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2})^n$$
$$Let \ \ z=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$r = |z| = \sqrt{ (\frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2} = 1$$
$$\sin\theta = \frac{y}{r} \ \ , \ \ \cos\theta = \frac{x}{r}$$
$$\sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ \ , \ \ \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}$$
Here both $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are in 1st quadrant so
$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$$ 
$$\operatorname{Arg} z = \frac{\pi}{3}$$